# Docusign API Integration for Real Estate Web Application

Tags: docusignapi

I'm developing a web application for real estate agents and their clients to easily handle offer management for real estate transactions. Using docusign's API, I'm hoping to allow my users to use embedded signing features to sign and submit documents regarding offers of their transaction.

The major issue/problem we want to solve is allowing local access to the docusign documents natively within our web application. Meaning, if a user submits a document on our platform, and requests multiple parties to sign the given document, we would like to keep a live copy within our application as it gets signed by multiple parties.

Currently, most implementations of the API simply send over the original document to docusign, and use their backend to update and notify parties when signatures have been requested or completed; meanwhile the original document submitted by the user to the platform, remains in it's original condition without any updates or changes; which can be confusing for users of the platform to keep track of the document status.

Any help in regards to solving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Is this possible? if so what tools and services are required to achieve this.

Comment: Answered below. Let me know if it's helpful by upvoting and accepting the answer. Thanks! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Meaning, if a user submits a document on our platform, and requests
>   multiple parties to sign the given document, we would like to keep a
>   live copy within our application as it gets signed by multiple
>   parties.

I have a couple suggestions. Let me know if either is what you're looking for:

First, you can call `GET /envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{doucmentId}` to retrieve docs from an envelope. [Here's a link to more info on this endpoint.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get)

Now, it also sounds like you may want to provide your realtor users with envelope status in real-time. There are a couple of ways to accomplish this, but one is greatly preferred.

Technically you CAN retrieve information about your envelopes by calling `GET /envelopes?include=recipients,tabs`. On your front end, this enables you to dynamically update components, such as a color-coded status column indicating to users where their agreements are in the pipeline. Downside here is that there are [polling restrictions](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits), which limit you to one such call every 15 minutes.

The preferred method is to use the [Connect webhook notification service](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect). When you create a connect configuration in your account, you can proactively receive information about your envelopes moments after events occur. (We'll ping you.) Then you can update front end components to keep your agents in the know.

Here's a sample connect notification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
      <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
          <RecipientStatus>
            <Type>Signer</Type>
            <Email>user.email@address.com</Email>
            <UserName>User Name</UserName>
            <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
            <Sent>2010-06-26T09:19:18.883</Sent>
            <Delivered>2010-06-26T09:19:40.723</Delivered>
            <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
            <Status>Delivered</Status>
            <RecipientIPAddress>::1</RecipientIPAddress>
            <CustomFields />
            <TabStatuses>
              <TabStatus>
                <TabType>Custom</TabType>
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <XPosition>364</XPosition>
                <YPosition>52</YPosition>
                <TabLabel>Radio</TabLabel>
                <TabName>Two</TabName>
                <TabValue />
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
                <OriginalValue />
                <ValidationPattern />
                <RoleName>TestRole</RoleName>
              </TabStatus>
            </TabStatuses>
            <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
            <RecipientId>fb89d2ee-2876-4290-b530-ff1833d5d0d2</RecipientId>
          </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>2010-06-26T09:19:45.771206-07:00</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>0aa561b8-b4d9-47e0-a615-2367971f876b</EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates Test</Subject>
        <UserName>User Name</UserName>
        <Email> user.email@address.com </Email>
        <Status>Delivered</Status>
        <Created>2010-06-26T09:16:21.27</Created>
        <Sent>2010-06-26T09:19:19.01</Sent>
        <Delivered>2010-06-26T09:19:40.747</Delivered>
        <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>2010-06-26T09:16:21.27</ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>ACHolder Name</ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail> ACHolder.email@address.com </ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>ACHolder Location</ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>::1            </SenderIPAddress>
        <EnvelopePDFHash />
        <CustomFields>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>Envelope Field 1</Name>
            <Show>False</Show>
            <Required>False</Required>
            <Value />
          </CustomField>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>Envelope Field 2</Name>
            <Show>False</Show>
            <Required>False</Required>
            <Value />
          </CustomField>
        </CustomFields>
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
          <DocumentStatus>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>Document_Name</Name>
            <TemplateName>radio parents</TemplateName>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
          </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
      </EnvelopeStatus>
      <DocumentPDFs>
        <DocumentPDF>
          <Name>DocumentPDF_Name</Name>
          <PDFBytes>PDFBytes_Information</PDFBytes>
        </DocumentPDF>
      </DocumentPDFs>
    </DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

Comment: Glad to help! Be sure to upvote the answer too if you get a chance

Comment: I would like to get in contact with either you or another developer in regards to hiring an expert to develop this integration for my web application. Please let me know if you or anyone you know is interested